# Java Main Method, Parameters Differences

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I've started learning Java and I was wondering the difference between:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {}
```

and

```
public static void main (String args[]) {}
```

As you can see they look almost exactly the same but my question here is, should the '[]' be before the args or after the args? I have a Java beginners guide and it shows me examples with the '[]' after the args. I would be grateful if someone could tell me the correct way.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String args[]` is an alternate (non standard) syntax for declaring an array, which is allowed as a carry over from C (java is based on C), probably to ease the transition to java from C. You hardly ever see it used.

And by the way there's a *third* valid signature for the main method:

```
public static void main (String... args) {}
```

Comment: Worth nothing that the third option only works when the array is the last argument in the list.

Comment: @DuncanJones with the `main` method, there is only the array parameter

Comment: @Jones: You are right.But here it is always last element.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes... I know! :-)  I'm just adding a note for future readers, who may think this is a completely synonymous replacement for the `Foo[] bar` or `Foo bar[]` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In the public static void main(String args[])

args is an array of String type.
So for declaring we do this ways String args[] or String []args

So both are same

Answer (score 0):

Both of them have the same effect - they both declare an array. I find the first one far more readable. The second syntax was only added to help programmers who have come to Java from C.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work correctly.They represent the arguments to command line. String array